# How to navigate through a json file with Python 3? TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to get as many profile links as I can on khanacademy.org. I am using their api.

I am struggling navigating through the json file to get the desired data.

Here is my code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/discussions/video/what-are-algorithms/questions?casing=camel&limit=10&page=0&sort=1&lang=en&_=190422-1711-072ca2269550_1556031278137") as response:
    source = response.read()

data= json.loads(source)

for item in data['feedback']:
    print(item['authorKaid'])
    profile_answers = item['answers']['authorKaid']
    print(profile_answers)
```

My goal is to get as many `authorKaid` as possible en then store them (to create a database later).

When I run this code I get this error :
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I don't understand why, on this tutorial video : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I` at `16:10` it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is `item['answers']` are lists and you are trying to access by a string rather than an index value. So when you try to get `item['answers']['authorKaid']` there is the error:

What you really want is

```
print (item['answers'][0]['authorKaid'])
print (item['answers'][1]['authorKaid'])
print (item['answers'][2]['authorKaid'])
etc...
```

So you're actually wanting to iterate through those lists. Try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen("https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/discussions/video/what-are-algorithms/questions?casing=camel&limit=10&page=0&sort=1&lang=en&_=190422-1711-072ca2269550_1556031278137") as response:
    source = response.read()

data= json.loads(source)

for item in data['feedback']:
    print(item['authorKaid'])
    for each in item['answers']:
        profile_answers = each['authorKaid']
        print(profile_answers)
```